# Create heatmap using pandas TimeSeries

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I need to create MatplotLib heatmap (pcolormesh) using Pandas DataFrame TimeSeries column (df_all.ts) as my X-axis.

How to convert Pandas TimeSeries column to something which can be used as X-axis in  np.meshgrid(x, y) function to create heatmap? The workaround is to create Matplotlib drange using same parameters as in pandas column, but is there a simple way?

```
x = pd.date_range(df_all.ts.min(),df_all.ts.max(),freq='H')
xt = mdates.drange(df_all.ts.min(), df_all.ts.max(), dt.timedelta(hours=1))
y = arange(ylen)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xt, y)
```

Comment: Without a clear definition of what you want, i assume your heatmap is a simple 2D histogram. So why dont you resample/pivot your DF to this and plot it with `plt.imshow(df_all.values)`?

Comment: I need only 5-20 items on axis Y, as I understand the imshow() requires to specify every point of histogram

Comment: You can always re-label the axis according to the data that's in the TimeSeries column. Don't stress on forcing the matplotlib functions to use exactly that data as the x-axis data if plotting as an image works and then adjust the axis labels.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by heat map for a time series, but for a dataframe you may do as below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from itertools import product
from string import ascii_uppercase
from matplotlib import patheffects

m, n = 4, 7 # 4 rows, 7 columns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(m, n),
                  columns=list(ascii_uppercase[:n]),
                  index=list(ascii_uppercase[-m:]))


ax = plt.imshow(df, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Oranges').axes

_ = ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, n-1, n))
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
_ = ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, m-1, m))
_ = ax.set_yticklabels(df.index)

ax.grid('off')
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
```

optionally, to print actual values in the middle of each square, with some shadows for readability, you may do:

```
path_effects = [patheffects.withSimplePatchShadow(shadow_rgbFace=(1,1,1))]

for i, j in product(range(m), range(n)):
    _ = ax.text(j, i, '{0:.2f}'.format(df.iloc[i, j]),
                size='medium', ha='center', va='center',
                path_effects=path_effects)
```

[image: heat-map]

Comment: But is there way with your approach to format dates if I have hundreds points on X with minute interval, but I need to show daily ticks only?

Comment: @szu if you want the heat map to be also based on daily intervals, then you need to first use pandas `resample` method, otherwise just modify `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` calls

Comment: @behzad.nouri When i run the print actual value code, I got this error:     "ax.text(j, i, '{:.2f}'.format(df.iget_value(i, j)),
ValueError: zero length field name in format"  Do u know why? Pandas version 0.14.1 and python 2.6.6

Comment: @AnthonyKong not sure, try with `df.iloc[i, j]`

Comment: @behzad.nouri Sorry, just figure it out: "'{:.2f}'.format(" is not valid python 2.x code