# Show values over matplotlib imshow plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm relatively new to Pythons' matplotlib, but as it happens I'm using it to visualize some data.

For instance, I have some fractions that represents a relation between some classes. In order to visualize their relation in using `pyplot.imshow` and it does great to visualize the relation. But, It would be nice if I could visualize the values that gave rise to the fraction. As It happens I couldn't accomplish this, but I made a mock-up of how I think this should be. Does anyone have an idea ?

[image: Data visualization mock-up]

So thanks to @behzad.nouri for his answer in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520246/create-heatmap-using-pandas-timeseries/20523271#20523271) I could put together the code to do what I needed. So for future reference (please, bear in mind that this possibly isn't the most pythonic way to do things):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import patheffects
from matplotlib import cm

a_size = 5
foo_o = np.random.random_integers(30, size=(a_size, a_size))

foo_m = np.zeros([a_size, a_size])

for i in xrange(a_size):
    for j in xrange(a_size):
            _sum = foo_o[i][i] + foo_o[j][j]
            comb = foo_o[i][j]
            foo_m[i][j] = float(comb)/float(_sum)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.imshow(foo_m, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='None', origin='lower', aspect='auto')

for i in xrange(a_size):
    for j in xrange(a_size):
        ax.text(j, i, '{:.2f}'.format(foo_o[i][j]),
                size='medium', ha='center', va='center',
                path_effects=[patheffects.withSimplePatchShadow(shadow_rgbFace=(1, 1, 1))])
plt.show()
```

With this the following result is produced:
[image]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523271/625914) may be helpful

Comment: Yeah it seems to do exactly what I hoped! I'll test and report back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'll edit my question with our code if you don't mind

Comment: Usually it is recommended to answer your own question, and to accept that. That is to make it more obvious that the problem was already solved.