# Visualize 3 columns as a heatmap in seaborn / pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

Say I have a dataframe like the following, with one row for each day and hour in the week:

```
   day  hour     price
0    0     0  0.875977
1    0     1  0.503724
2    0     2  0.392934
3    0     3  0.199421
4    0     4  0.172832
```

I am hoping to visualize this data. My first thought is to use a heatmap. Is there a way to do this easily with `seaborn` or `pandas`?

I can probably convert this to a matrix and see it as a `plt.imshow()` but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something already exists for this.

Comment: On the agenda for seaborn, but not implemented yet.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523271/625914