# Python pandas and matplotlib pcolormesh doesn't work?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

How come this works:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3},
    'B':{'A':4,'B':5,'C':6},
    'C':{'A':7,'B':8,'C':9}})
plt.pcolor(df)
```

But `plt.pcolormesh(df)` doesn't work? Specifically I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

I prefer `pcolormesh` over `pcolor`, because it is faster. I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520246/create-heatmap-using-pandas-timeseries) that I can just do `plt.imshow(df, interpolation='nearest')`, but I'm still curious to know, why `pcolormesh` doesn't work.

Comment: you can plot with `plt.pcolormesh(df.values)`.

Comment: it seems pretty obvious that `pcolormesh` doesn't work because it assumes the input is a `numpy` `array` -- i.e., has a `ravel` method.  is your question, "why don't the `numpy` developers change this?"  that question would be better posed to them.  hit up that mailing list.

Comment: @dbliss Thanks for answering the question. It seems odd that these two methods don't take the same input. I will get on the relevant mailing list. Thanks.