# How to plot Time Series Heatmap with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, heatmap

*I want to draw a chart with x-axis as timeline, y-axis as its value and the color will indicate its frequency. The higher the frequency, the deeper the color is.*

[image: Here is the chart I want to draw]

Comment: I am not sure if seaborn line plot does what you want but have a look here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520246/create-heatmap-using-pandas-timeseries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a 2d histogram:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist2d(x, y)
```

The default plot is not as pretty as your example, but you can play with it and change the colormap, bins, ...

**Edit:**

This produces a plot much closer to your example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# example data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
y = 0.5*x+np.random.randn(10000)

# make a custom colormap with transparency
ncolors = 256
color_array = plt.get_cmap('YlOrRd')(range(ncolors))
color_array[:, -1] = np.linspace(0, 1, ncolors)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='YlOrRd_alpha', colors=color_array)

plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=[15, 30], cmap=cmap, edgecolor='white')
plt.show()
```

The result is:
[image]

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you! It's a great hint, let me try first.

Comment: I have modified the answer and now it looks very much like your example. Take a look!

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!