# Extracting values needed for a histogram heatmap from an array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list/array(?) in this format

[image]

```
data = [[1,1,2],[4,3,3,8,1],[2,3,4]]
```

(The real list is much longer with more days and temperatures)

How do I get x and y needed for this function?

```
plt.hist2d(x, y)
```

Background:
I would like to make a time series heatmap like here: [How to plot Time Series Heatmap with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186769/how-to-plot-time-series-heatmap-with-python) , where **x axis is days**, **y axis is temperature** and **hue is the frequency** of a specific temperature in that day

### Update

Seems like I got it to work by modifying @Guldborg92 's answer

```
x = []
y = []
for day in range(0, len(data)):
    for temperature in data[day]:
        x.append(day)
        y.append(temperature)

    plt.hist2d(x, y)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts?Which elements in `data` correspond to which plot elements? it's a ragged array right now with no clear way of knowing what your expected output is

Comment: Originally i tried doing `plt.hist2d(data)`, but that obviously doesn't work because it requires two arguments, _x_ and _y_. I'm wondering how I can get _x_ and _y_ values from the array. The format of `data` is the following `[[temp1_of_day1, temp2_of_day1],[temp1_of_day_2, temp2_of_day2]]` @g-anderson

Comment: That still doesn't clear it up, unfortunately. The list you posted has three sublists of different lengths, so is that `[[day1, day2, day3],[day1, day2, day3, day4, day5],[day1, day2, day3]]`?

Comment: No. I have edited the post with an image that hopefully clarifies my intention @G.Anderson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more pythonic version using comprehensions instead of loops:

```py
x = [day for day, temps in enumerate(data) for _ in temps]
y = [temp for day in data for temp in day]

plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=[15, 30], cmap='OrRd')
```

[image: hist2d of temps by day]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your data structure correctly then you can flatten the data in a nested for loop like this:

```
data = [[1,1,2], [4,3,3,8,1], [2,3,4]]

for day in range(0, len(data)):
    for temperature in data[day]:
        plt.hist2d(day + 1, temperature)
```

Comment: Oddly enough it returns `list index out of range`

Comment: I modiefied your code and it seems to work now. I've updated the post.

Comment: I see. `hist2d` takes arrays or shapes as arguments. That's why constructing lists will fix the error. However you are accumulating your lists in the for loop, which will give you some incorrect data in day 2, 3 etc. You can fix that by moving your array declarations within the nested loop :-)